# How to call 2 different actions at the same time / access them from JSP page in Struts 2?

Tags: jsp, struts2, scope, action

I'm developing a Struts2 application. In order to remove duplicated code, I want to have access to an Action (let's call it `A`) in 2 different JSP pages (let's say `page_1.jsp` and `page_2.jsp`). So far, so good. The problem is that in each of these 2 JSP pages, I also need to have simultaneous access to an additional action: `B` and `C`, respectively.

**To summarize:** `page_1.jsp` needs access to Actions `A` and `B`, while `page_2.jsp` needs access to Actions `A` and `C`. How would I get that? As far as I know, using `type = "redirectAction"` in `struts.xml` won't work, because it only redirects the action, so the JSP page will only have access to the last action called.

**Example:**

```
<action name="A" class="package.action.A" method="execute">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">B</result>
</action>

<action name="B" class="package.action.B" method="execute">
    <result name="success">page_1.jsp</result>
</action>
```

As far as I know, in the example above `page_1.jsp` will only have access to action `B`, right?

**EDIT:**

In fact, class `A` is named `CreateArchitecturesAction` - I need to access it on actions `B` and `C`, in order to populate a similar `<s:radio>` tag on both. The code is as simple as this:

```
public class CreateArchitecturesAction extends ActionSupport
{
    private List<String> architectures;

    private static final String intel32 = "Intel 32 Bit", intel64 = "Intel 64 Bit";

    public String execute()
    {
        architectures = new ArrayList<String>();
        architectures.add(intel32);
        architectures.add(intel64);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<String> getArchitectures()
    {
        return architectures;
    }

    public String getDefaultArchitectureValue()
    {
        return intel32;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "access to". You *could* use the `<s:action>` tag, or action chaining, but ew, don't do that. It really depends on what you're actually trying to do; it sounds like your functionality lives in the wrong place(s) right now.

Comment: Basically, "`A`" is a very simple Action class, it just creates and populates an ArrayList (please see edit above). I need to access it in actions `B` and `C` to populate a similar `<s:radio>` tag on both. Didn't tested it yet, but judging by the description on the [`<s:action>` documentation page](https://struts.apache.org/docs/action.html), it seems to be just what I need.

Comment: Again, I'd recommend against it, and suggest that your functionality lives in the wrong place. Put the list generation into a utility class of some sort, and either inject it into each action that needs it (e.g., if you're using Spring/etc) or just call it manually. Tying actions together in the way you're going is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Why don't you just create a base action class and extend it?

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I've been thinking a little, and since this list will certainly increase over time, I think the most appropriate solution is to simply store it on the database, and retrieve with it with EclipseLink (which I have been using). I can't even understand why I haven't thought of this before...

Answer (score 1):

Only one action you have access from JSP, however you can have access to any scope available in JSP after the page is dispatched. So this flow

```xml
<action name="A" class="package.action.A" method="execute">
    <result name="success" type="dispatcher">B</result>
</action>

<action name="B" class="package.action.B" method="execute">
    <result name="success">page_1.jsp</result>
</action>
```

You can have access to action `B` if you change the scope of the action to request scoped.

Comment: Concerning your suggestion, I read [this](https://struts.apache.org/docs/accessing-application-session-request-objects.html). On the other hand, @Dave Newton suggested using a [`<s:action>`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/action.html) tag. The latter option seems to be what I need (please see the edit on the original post to understand better the context & what I'm looking for). What do you think suits best my needs?

Comment: You asked a different question, but I recommend you refrain from `s:action`, it is used if you want to invoke action from JSP. I would in your case either use Struts container to adjust the scope of the action bean, or delegate it to Spring  where request scope is implemented. On the other hand you can try the arsenal of interceptors to change the scope of the variable inside the action or conversation plugin. But it's used in more complex scenarios, in your case/and my answer request attributes accessible when you forward to another action. The filter should have init param of course.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. It really seems I have several options available. I've been thinking a little, and since this list will certainly increase over time, I concluded that the most appropriate solution seems to be simply storing it on the database, and retrieve with it with EclipseLink (which I have been using). I can't even understand why I haven't thought of this before...